# How can I make java look at the previous value in an arrayList and return an error if it is the same as the next?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a created a arrayList, made a getter class, and have made a method, in the method what I want to do is perform 2 error checks... 1 if the value user is going to add has already been added just before it will give an error.

say for example, in the list there is apple, banana .... if the user tries to add banana again it should give an error.

Also if the list contains 2 same values then java should not allow any more of that type to be added, and should provide an error.

Thanks.

Comment: And what is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: For the first problem: Check the previous last item before adding. For the second problem: Looks like you'll have to go through your list and see how often the value to add has already been added. Give it a try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: You must share your code.!

Comment: What @HugoSousa said. Also, I'm a little confused. What is a "getter class"? Why does it have a method that seems to append, contrary to what its name suggests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ArrayList.contains(object) method to check to see if the ArrayList contains the same object, but it sounds like you want to check for type of object. I wouldn't use an ArrayList. I would use a HashMap, set the key for each type, then  check to see if the HashMap has an entry using HashMap.hasKey() method. If you absolutely must use an ArrayList, you're going to have to iterate through the array each time you want to add something and check each item.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is simple. Just check list.size()-1 to see if the object you want to add is the same as the previous one.
In regards to the second problem, an efficient way to do it is to use a `HashMap<String,Integer>`. Every time you add an object to the list see if it exists in the Hashmap already, and if so increment its counter.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to help me out if I upload my code, I am new to java and still trying to get my head around it. I will really appreciate if you can.

Answer (score 0):

**Function to add element to an array:**

```
public static <T> void addToArray( final ArrayList<T> array, final T element ) {
    if ( array.size() > 0 )
    {
        int count = 0;
        for ( T item : array )
            if ( item.equals( element ) )
            {
                ++count;
                if ( count > 1 )
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Too many repeated values." );
            }
        if ( array.get( array.size() - 1 ).equals( element ) )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Same as tail value." );
    }
    array.add( element );
}
```

**Testing this:**

```
public static void main( final String[] args ) {
    final ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    addToArray( strings, "apple" );
    addToArray( strings, "banana" );
    addToArray( strings, "apple" );
    addToArray( strings, "cherry" );
    try {
        addToArray( strings, "cherry" );
    } catch( IllegalArgumentException e ){
        System.err.println( e.getMessage() );
    };
    try {
        addToArray( strings, "apple" );
    } catch( IllegalArgumentException e ){
        System.err.println( e.getMessage() );
    };
    System.out.println( strings );
}
```

**System.err output**

```
Same as tail value.
Too many repeated values.
```

**System.out output**

```
[apple, banana, apple, cherry]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but I tried adapting it to mine by changing the arraylist name and the place where it is getting stored but it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can go with that code:

```
public class Deneme
{

    private  static Scanner input;
    private static ArrayList<String> arr;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        arr = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a value: ");
            String val = input.nextLine();
            if (arr.contains(val))
                System.out
                        .println("Please enter some other value you've already entered : "
                                + val);
            else
                arr.add(val);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This does not crash if an item is added a third time, as specified by the OP.